# Sqoop with duplicate column name

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I wrote a sqoop with duplicate column name (have alias) but it threw me an error message "Duplicate Column identifier specified: 'id'". I modified sqoop to have concat function and now it gives me an error "Hive does not support the SQL type for column a"

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://foo.test.net/mfg \
--username pingp \
--password 987yjd \
--hive-import  \
--hive-table third_map \
--query "select concat(r.id,'') a, concat(p.id,'') b from tblDimMfg r join tblDimMfg p on r.id = p.id where r.Name = 'bbp' and p.Name = 'bbt' and \$CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /user/test/hivehome/mysql/third_map \
--fields-terminated-by '\t' \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
-m 1
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you,
Rio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is the create a sub-select where the duplicate column names are then it works.